# difference between "been" and "gone"

Tags: word-choice, present-perfect, been-vs-gone

The difference between  "She's gone to London" and "she's been to London" is clear

but there is a sentence that I doubt what to use.

what should I use in this sentence?
(been or gone)

> The refrigerator is full because we've  ...... shopping

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage would be:

> The refrigerator is full because we've been shopping.

The use of "gone" in this sentence would otherwise imply that the refrigerator somehow refilled itself whilst you were still out shopping.

---

This is similar to the logic of your first example:

> She's gone to London

Implies that she remains in London.

Whereas:

> She's been to London

Implies that she visited London and has now returned.

Comment: Disagree. To me, both are correct, and the more natural version is with "*gone*"