# “has [been/gone] there for three days”

Tags: present-perfect, been-vs-gone

As we know the meaning of (has/have been to) is he or she came back.
So, how could we say the following?

> She has **been** there for three days

I think it is wrong to say so. We should say

> She has **gone** there for three days

Which one is right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between "been" and "gone"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/185984/difference-between-been-and-gone)

Comment: They're not similar .. Read the 2 questions first.

Comment: @LeeMac your answer in the linked question is incomplete, and in any case doesn't apply to this situation where the person is still wherever she has gone to.  Moreover it doesn't address the grammatical mistakes in Karim's question.  The close vote is not justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Has been there/here" does not always imply that the person is no longer at the location. For example:

> A: Is your father at home?
>
> B: Yes, he has been there all day.

or

> A: Have you been to this restaurant before?
>
> B: Yes, I have been here. I came here last week.

In the first example, the father is still at home and has not left. In the second example, the person was at the restaurant last week, left, and came back.

The [present perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect) expresses a past event that has consequences right now. You can say that someone has been somewhere both if they have gone there and come back and if they are still there.

---

However, your example with the verb "gone" does not work. When someone goes somewhere, the action ceases once they arrive. Therefore the below example would imply that the woman has gone to the destination and then returned (or at least gone somewhere else) on each of the three days.

> She has gone there for three days.

would be better written as

> She has gone there every day for three days.

The sentence most certainly does not mean that she arrived three days ago and has remained there the entire time.